# Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax to rest web service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

Hi i'm trying to upload file using jquery ajax to rest web service.

HTML:

```
<form id="myFormID" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="myId" />
</form>
```

Jquery ajax code is.

```
$('#myId').click(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'url',
        dataType : "json",
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data :formData  ,
        async : true,
        processData : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) {                  

        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

web service code is....

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadfile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputString,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {

    saveToDisk(fileInputString , fileInputDetails);
    return "File Uploaded Sucessfully!!!";
}

public void saveToDisk(
    InputStream fileInputString,
    FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {

    String uploadedFileLocation="d://upload/image";
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new  File(uploadedFileLocation));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = fileInputString.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);       
        }
        out.flush();  
        out.close();                

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting internal server error in my application:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init()

Comment: You can't upload files through ajax like that. Use a FileReader object to post your image as base64 and decode it server side, for example. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader]